# Ion-icon not tappable together with ion-datetime on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-item` which contains an `ion-datetime` and an `ion-icon`. 
In both platforms, when clicking the datetime container it opens the date picker. In iOS, when clicking the icon (calendar icon) it opens the date picker. But in Android, it does nothing.

I've tried changing the `z-index` of the `.calendar-icon` to `-X` but it removes the icon from the datetime input.

```css
.calendar-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ion-item >
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"></ion-datetime>
  <ion-icon class="calendar-icon" name="calendar-outline" item-right></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

The expectation is that it will be the same with iOS that if the calendar icon is clicked, in Android, it will show the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 4 you can do something like in the attached code snippet. No need for additional CSS. You can find more information about `ion-datetime` usage in [Ionic official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime).

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@latest/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@latest/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<ion-card>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-datetime dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="Select date"></ion-datetime>
    <ion-icon name="calendar" slot="end"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```